# ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN failed because 'rowguid' is currently replicated

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

We have a SQL Server 2012 database that was migrated from SQL Server 2000. The 2000 version had replication on it, but this was removed.

I am currently trying to remove a few deprecated columns in several tables, but I'm getting the following message:

```
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN failed because 'rowguid' is currently replicated.
```

As far as I can see, neither the server nor the database have any remains of replication. The triggers, system tables - everything is gone.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Any replication related constraints in this table?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but maybe this will work try Executing this proc on Publisher Server

```
EXECUTE sp_repldropcolumn @tblname, @colname
```

and then try to alter your table.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, and I got back the response

    Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_repldropcolumn, Line 191
Invalid object name 'sysmergearticles'.

Answer (score 0):

If replication isn't supposed to be configured for this database at all, try dropping the hammer on it. Something like this:

```
exec sp_replicationdboption 'yourdb', 'publish', 'true', 1
exec sp_replicationdboption 'yourdb', 'publish', 'false', 1
exec sp_removedbreplication 'yourdb'
```